# how to parse this in iphone

Tags: iphone, parsing

```
{

    education =     (
                {
            school =             {
                id = 108102169223234;
                name = psss;
            };
            type = College;
            year =             {
                id = 142833822398097;
                name = 2010;
            };
        }
    );
    email = "amvijaycse@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = Vijay;
    gender = male;
    id = 100000782204693;
    "last_name" = Kumar;
    link = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000782204693";
    locale = "en_US";
    location =     {
        id = 106377336067638;
        name = "Bangalore, India";
    };
    name = "Vijay Kumar";
    timezone = "5.5";
    "updated_time" = "2010-11-21T07:45:11+0000";
}
```

i needed email,firstname,lastname.

Comment: It looks like the log when printing the NSDictionary contents

Comment: What's the data source for the above?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: Removed because it was inaccurate]

Comment: oops, my bad, just assumed it was as soon as I saw parsing and parenthesis, Will delete in a few.